# How to get date from cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've got function in VBA that operates with dates from cells. But I got `By ref error` when I choose cells. What can be the problem? This is my code

```
Function DifferenceInYears(existdate As Date, estimdate As Date) As Double

    Dim yearDifference As Integer
    Dim monthDifference As Integer
    Dim dayDifference As Integer
    yearDifference = 0
    monthDifference = 0
    dayDifference = 0
    If (estimdate <= existdate) Then
        MsgBox "Input correct range"
        GoTo myerr
    End If
    Dim tempDate As Date
    IsDateLeapDay = False
    Dim existYear As String
    Dim estimYear As String
    existYear = Year(existdate)
    estimYear = Year(estimdate)
    estimMonth = Month(estimdate)
    existMonth = Month(existdate)

    and so on...
```

Comment: **Post the full UDF.**

Comment: It's very big. I got error in `DifferenceInYears(existdate As Date, estimdate As Date)`

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? At which line you are getting the error?

Comment: For one thing, you should use DateDiff for your date difference calculations: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/datediff.php

Comment: Is that a function to be used in a sheet ? If yes, it should NOT have a MsgBox in it. Also show us how you call the function.

Comment: By the way, the difference in Years is just `(Date2-Date1)/365`. No need to write a function for that !

Comment: If your function is meant to be used in a sheet, your aguments must be of `Range` type !!!

Comment: It's not usual difference in dates

Answer (score 5):

This should get you started:

```
Sub GetDatesAndComputeElapsedYears()

   Dim d1 As String
   Dim d2 As String

   d1 = Range("a2").Value2 'put a date in A2 Formatted as date(cell format)
   d2 = Range("b2").Value2 'put a date in B2 Formaated as date(cell format)

   Dim date1 As Date
   Dim date2 As Date

   date1 = CDate(d1) 'converts serialized date to DATE Object
   date2 = CDate(d2)

   Dim years

   years = DateDiff("yyyy", date1, date2) 'use this for date difference calculations

   MsgBox CStr(years), vbOKOnly, "Years Elapsed"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but whatever function is calling this code, is NOT passing in an actual VB `Date`, and since you haven't qualified your arguments with the `ByVal`, VB assumes it to be `ByRef`. (Prefixing nothing—which is what you've done—is the same as prefixing with `ByRef`.) E.g.,

```
existdate As Date
```

is the same as

```
ByRef existdate As Date
```

But much different than

```
ByVal existdate As Date
```

You can try to make the arguments `ByVal`. Or you can change the argument type to Variant (which is what a Cell's value actually is, and what I'm guessing you're actually passing in).

Try changing your method signature to this:

```
Function DifferenceInYears(ByVal existdate As Date, ByVal estimdate As Date) As Double
```

...or this:

```
Function DifferenceInYears(existdate As Variant, estimdate As Variant) As Double
```

You'll probably have to do some casting inside or outside the function, but that should get you closer and solve your `By ref error` issue.

Comment: I try both variants and the didn't work, I got the same error.

Comment: Then try adding "ByVal" to each parameter. This IS your issue! You are trying to cast a value which cannot be done when passing 'ByRef'.

Comment: If that helps I pass params like DifferenceInYears(D29;D30). And I already add Byval to both of my params and thats didn't help

Comment: If D29 is a cell, then your trying to pass in an Object, which, your right, won't work even if it's ByVal. If D29 is a cell, then pass in the value of the Cell, like this `DifferenceInYears(D29.Value, D30.Value)`
---
Wait a minute, is that a semi-colon?

Comment: Yes, its's cell. But dates can be in different cells. How can I do that?

Comment: `DifferenceInYears(Sheet1.Cells(29,4).Value, Sheet1.Cells(30,4).Value)`

This assumes the sheet of the cells you wan't are on `Sheet1`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88206/discussion-between---and-limanighthawk).