# excel: gets date and add one day

Tags: vba, excel

I have this simple spreadsheet with names and a few dates.

What I want to happen is that if some conditions were true, I'll get the end date (column H) of the first sheet and copy it to my second sheet (column G) and add onde more day to it.

This is the first sheet, called `BASE_TOTAL`.

[image]

And this is the second one, called `APOIOS`.

[image]

The "sss" represents where I want to enter with the date plus one day.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub Apoios()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim res

Set ws1 = Sheets("Plan3")
Set ws2 = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL")
Set ws3 = Sheets("APOIOS")

lastrow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    For j = 1 To 11
        Select Case True
            Case IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(i, j)):
                ws3.Cells(i, j) = ""

            Case Not IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(i, j)):
                If ws1.Cells(4, 3) <= ws2.Cells(i, 8) And ws2.Cells(i, 5).Value <> "APOIO" Then
                    ws3.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 2)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 3)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 4).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 4)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 5).Value = "APOIO"
                    ws3.Cells(i, 6).Value = "-"
                    ws3.Cells(i, 7).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 8).Value + 1 
                    ws3.Cells(i, 8).Value = "-------------"
                    ws3.Cells(i, 9).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 9)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 10).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 10)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 11).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 11)
                End If

        End Select
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

As you can see, I tried to do that with this line of code:

```
ws3.Cells(i, 7).Value = ws3.Cells(i, 8).Value + 1
```

But it didn't work out. I'm kind of new with VBA so I don't know which function I should use to understand that I want the date on that cell and add one more day.

I know that exists `DateSerial` function, but I don't know how to apply it with this example. I also find [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32273186/6088173) answer and I'll check if it works.
Although my dates are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Any suggestions will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the DateAdd function?
Like

```
ws3.Cells(i, 7).Value = DateAdd("d", 1, ws2.Cells(i, 8).Value)
```

Comment: I get this line highlighted with a type mismatch error.

Comment: I just tested it and it worked for me. 
are the columns formated as Dates? or is there some data that is not a date in the column?

Comment: The whole column is formated as date, but my dates are in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. This function gets that or I need to modify something?

Comment: in your example some of the rows are "-" maybe thats the reason? the dateformat should not make a difference

Comment: Yes, you're right, that was my problem, thanks. Although I needed to use this "-" in some rows I'll find a way to fix that later.